# How to calculate total working time in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have a table which holds clocking in/out records for every user :

```
RecID   User    In/Out  ClockInOutTime
8      1       IN      25/02/2011 09:36:44
9      1       OUT     25/02/2011 11:36:44
10    1       IN      25/02/2011 12:36:44
11    1       OUT     25/02/2011 17:36:44
12    1       IN      26/02/2011 00:00:00
13    1       OUT     26/02/2011 12:00:00
14    1       IN      26/02/2011 09:00:44
15    1       OUT     26/02/2011 12:36:44
```

Any ideas how I can work out the total time worked for every month using LINQ?

cheers

Comment: First I'd try to solve it in TSQL; if you can't solve it easily in TSQL it probably isn't suitable for LINQ. Dare I say it, but a row per shift with `ClockInTime` and `ClockOutTime` would have made this a lot easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial to do in either Linq or SQL. There is no easy way to link each OUT record with the corresponding IN record in SQL.

You have two options:

1. Querying the data and calculating in code within a for loop.
2. Changing the table schema like: `RecID, User, ClockInTime, ClockOutTime`

Option 1 is easy to implement, but I would seriously consider option 2. How do you define in your business rules that each `IN` record must be followed by a corresponding `OUT` record (or be last record)?

Comment: How would I manage if they clocked in and out several times a day. I couldn't have a column for every one so that's why i did it on a row basis, but I know what you mean :)

Comment: @user583341 If you don't want to call each row a 'shift', call it a 'clock-in period' - it just defines a clock in and clock out time.  At least that way the two times are linked.

Comment: @user583341: Every time you clock in, you create a new record. Every time you clock out, you update the last record. Before creating a new record, you must check that isn't already a record with ClockOutTime set to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[ClockInOutTime], GETDATE()))
     FROM [swp].[dbo].[Table_1] t1
     WHERE [In/Out] = 'IN'
     AND t1.[User] = t.[User]) -
     Coalesce((SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[ClockInOutTime], GETDATE()))
     FROM [swp].[dbo].[Table_1] t2
     WHERE [In/Out] = 'OUT'
     AND t2.[User] = t.[User]),0)
  FROM [swp].[dbo].[Table_1] t   
  GROUP BY [User]
```

SQL way to solve this, not the best, but works even when last event don't have OUT timestamp i.e when last session still hasn't been closed.

Comment: Wow, you are one brave SQL warrior. Step 2: convert this to Linq? :-)

Comment: You can make View in your database with that code and map it with EF, just like a table. It will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan output = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
using (var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
      var begin = enumerator.Current.ClockInOutTime;
      if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
        break;

      var end = enumerator.Current.ClockInOutTime;
      output += (end - begin);
    }
}
```

Yes, it isn't LINQ but I wanted to offer a solution - secondly, if the dates aren't alternating (so after an IN is always an OUT) it'll break.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to group the data by UserId and Month portion of the DateTime, and pass each group of ordered In/Out times to this function.

Comment: Of course - I went by the example in the question. Getting the data should be easy with linq though.

Comment: that could be a problem - if the user forgets to check out at the end of the day it will break

Comment: I've gotten this far..                                            var view_times = (from d in db.LogTimes
                  where d.EventDate.Value.Month == month &&
                  d.Employee.Username == username
                  group d by d.EventDate.Value.Day into g
                  select g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that will only use linq. This is due to the fact that you need to introduce error handling as well (if a user forgets to sign out, usually there is a maximum time that will be applied then etc).

I would group the data by user, order it by date time and then run through it in a for each and do the calculation within the for each.